# Dúvida com public class ListatbProdutoDTO : List<tbProdutoDTO> para que serve?

Tags: c#

Eu tenho essa classe DTO:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;


public class tbProdutoDTO
{
public tbProdutoDTO()
{
    this.dsDescricao = "";
    this.dsFornecedor = "";
}

public tbProdutoDTO(int idproduto, String dsdescricao, String dsfornecedor, float vlvalor, int qtestoque)
{
    this.idProduto = idproduto;
    this.dsDescricao = dsdescricao;
    this.dsFornecedor = dsfornecedor;
    this.vlValor = vlvalor;
    this.qtEstoque = qtestoque;
}

public int idProduto { get; set; }
public String dsDescricao { get; set; }
public String dsFornecedor { get; set; }
public float vlValor { get; set; }
public int qtEstoque { get; set; }

}
```

Agora por que eu preciso dessa classe? Segue classe:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;


public class ListatbProdutoDTO : List<tbProdutoDTO>
{
  public ListatbProdutoDTO()
  {
  }
}
```

Não consigo entender para que essa classe lista serve.

Comment: O que você quer fazer?

Comment: Não entendi esse generic aí como lista. Fazer um projeto venda....Essa classe peguei de um amigo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você **não "precisa"** dela realmente, até porque ela está vazia e não implementa nenhuma funcionalidade. Ou seja, no caso que você apresentou, utilizar `List<tbProdutoDTO>` ou utilizar `ListatbProdutoDTO` resultaria na mesma coisa.

**Mas quando a criação de uma classe que tem `List<T>` como base é útil?**

Bom, imagine que dentro de um sistema você sempre realiza algumas operações em cima de coleções de objetos da classe `Coisa`, e para não ficar repetindo o código dessas operações em vários lugares no sistema você resolveu criar vários métodos de ajuda, *helpers*. O problema é que agora você possui vários *helpers* que sempre irão trabalhar em cima de coleções de `Coisa`, `List<Coisa>`.

Você poderia agrupar esse métodos em uma classe separada para organizar mais o código, mas você pode fazer algo melhor, você pode criar uma coleção customizada, uma coleção de `Coisa` que implementa esses *helpers*.

Consegue imaginar o resultado? Seu código ficou mais organizado agora.

Abaixo elaborei um exemplo para que fique mais claro o que eu disse:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Criação de alguns dados de exemplo
        ListCoisa list = new ListCoisa
        {
            new Coisa { Id = 1, Descricao = "Coisinha", Preco = 10 },
            new Coisa { Id = 2, Descricao = "Coisa Normal", Preco = 20 },
            new Coisa { Id = 3, Descricao = "Coisona" , Preco = 30 }
        };

        // Utilizando o método CalcularTotal a partir do objeto ListCoisa
        Console.WriteLine(list.CalcularTotal());
        // Saída na tela: 60

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Coisa
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public decimal Preco { get; set; }
}

class ListCoisa : List<Coisa>
{
    public decimal CalcularTotal()
    {
        decimal total = 0;

        // Me referindo à coleção em si através da palavra-chave this
        foreach (Coisa coisa in this)
        {
            total += coisa.Preco;
        }

        return total;
    }
}
```